# Python CSV Reader Control Flow

Tags: python, csv, iterator

I was fairly surprised to see this functionality in Python's CSV reader.

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for i in range(3):
        sys.stdout.write('A ')
        for row in reader:
            sys.stdout.write('B ')

#sys.argv[1] is a 3 row csv file
```

I would normally expect code like this to print out something like:

```
A B B B A B B B A B B
```

But instead I get:

```
A B B A A
```

This seems to violate the basic flow control properties of for loops as I understand them. I mainly suspect that there is an unusual property of this iterator that results in this behavior. Any explanation would helpful and very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `reader` object from `csv.DictReader` is a generator. It got exhausted in the first iteration of the outer `for`. So in the following iterations, the inner `for` loop has no items to execute the loop.

Comment: Okay. I think I can fix that by switching the places of the two for loops. Thank you.

Comment: @LucaDelSignore Yes, you can. But you can also store the items from the reader in a `list`, if the csv file isn't too large

Comment: Actually, the real CSV file is very large.

Comment: Oh, then might be better to switch the loops

Comment: Thanks man. I appreciate the help and not getting down voted into oblivion for being inexperienced.